# Mysql create table with auto incrementing id giving error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I just can't find what's wrong with this code...

```
connection.query('CREATE TABLE posts (postid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, posttitle varchar(255) NOT NULL, postdate datetime NOT NULL, deleted boolean, ownerid int PRIMARY KEY (postid) )');
```

I get the error

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(postid) )' at line 1
```

I use node and mysql npm module. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a `,` between `ownerid int` and `PRIMARY KEY (postid)` as pointed below

```
ownerid int PRIMARY KEY (postid)
           ^...Here
```

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement should be

```
CREATE TABLE posts (postid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
posttitle varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
postdate datetime NOT NULL, 
deleted boolean, 
ownerid int, //Add comma here
 PRIMARY KEY (postid));
```

Comment: Praise the lord, it works! For some reason I thought the error was the the first occurence of the word 'postid'. I'm stupid...